# Non-pertubative renormalization and correctness of a theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, renormalization

Even if I start to understand why perturbative renormalization is necessary, I'm not exactly sure why non perturbative renormalization is.
After asking the question to several theorists, what I think I understood is that sometimes (all the time ?) **the theory is just wrong** (ie exact solutions are finite but doesn't correspond to experiments).

So lets take 4 examples : QED, QCD, GR, and Ising model.
For each of these examples :

- Is there some infinite results **without** perturbative development ?
- Is the renormalized theory the same as the non renormalized one ?
- How do we now that non perturbative renormalization is needed ?

For example I was told that QED has some non perturbative finite results, but that they are wrong, and that renormalized QED is a different theory that better match experimental results. On the other hand I think renormalization applied to Ising model is supposed to give the same results as the exact solution. 
I also don't understand why lattice QCD need renormalization, or how do we know that non pertubative naively quantized GR gives wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

If a theory contains divergences, there is no need to assume it is plain wrong. It probably won't be the full theory of everything, but that's the only criticism that can be leveled at it. It can still be in perfect agreement with experiments below very-high-energy.

The issue with QED is that QED is not a complete theory. In the real world, QED is just a part of the electroweak theory. This embedding solves all problems of defining QED nonperturbatively (as far as I know).

There is also the issue of renormalization group flow. Lattice QCD needs renormalization because the "fundamental" coupling is not the same as the physical one. If you put QCD on the lattice, your computer code will contain a value for the coupling. If you then measure the effective coupling in the simulations, it will be different, because you will be watching at a different, low-energy scale.

Comment: Then, in lattice QCD without renormalization, can I find a "fundamental" coupling constant that reproduce all experiments we can do ? I think the answer is no, otherwise we would not need renormalization

Comment: No, lattice QCD needs renormalization: the coupling constant plugged into the computer code depends on the lattice spacing. I put "fundamental" in square quotes because it is only fundamental in the lattice sense (i.e. it is defined at the fundamental scale of the simulation).

Comment: Anyway, even finding a fundamental coupling constant won't take away the need for renormalization. Grand Unified Theories contain more fundamental values for coupling constants, but those are not the same as the ones we measure. The QED coupling constant, for instance, will not have the same value at the GUT scale as at low energy.